# Divide report in parts

Tags: chapters, preamble, parts

I have the following preamble in LateX:

```
\documentclass[whitelogo,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
%\input{title}
%\input{abstract}
\tableofcontents
%\listoffigures
%\listoftables
\mainmatter

\part{Part 1}

\chapter{chapter-1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{chapter-2}
\lipsum[3-4]
\chapter{chapter-3}
\lipsum[5-6]
\chapter{chapter-4}
\lipsum[7-8]

\part{Part 2}

\chapter{chapter-4a}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{chapter-6}
\lipsum[3-4] 
\chapter{chapter-5}
\lipsum[5-6]
\chapter{chapter-7}
\lipsum[7-8]

\part{Part 3}

\chapter{chapter-8}
\lipsum[1-2]

\appendix
\chapter{appendix-a}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{appendix-b}
\lipsum[3-4]
\chapter{appendix-c}
\lipsum[5-6]

%\bibliography{./sources/library}
\end{document}
```

I want to divide my report first into **Part 1** (chapter 1 to 4), **Part 2** (chapter 4a to 7) and **Part 3** (chapter 8). When compiling the document, a long list of errors pops up, with different errors. How do I include 'Parts' into my document?

Comment: "A long list of errors" isn't particularly useful. What is the first error that you get? Anyway you can't use `\mainmatter` with the `report` class.

Comment: For sure, @campa is right, if you remove the `\mainmatter` it should work normally.

Answer (score 3):

When I run your minimal working example as you posted it, `pdflatex` freezes and says:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \mainmatter
```

This really tells you all you need to know, and means exactly what it appears to mean:  `pdflatex` ran into a control sequence which it didn't recognize (`\mainmatter`) on line 9 (`l.9`).  You can simply hit "enter" at this point, and it will resume processing and finish the file, outputting the following TOC:

[image: TOC of compiled document]

Which appears to be what you're trying to do.

And, indeed, if you simply delete the troublesome `\mainmatter` directive, you get the same output, cleanly compiling with no errors.

The reason is that `\mainmatter` is a book-ish thing (at least in the eyes of the definers of the standard LaTeX classes), and thus the `report` class doesn't define it.  (The `book` class defines `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, and `\backmatter` for book-like needs.)  `\mainmatter` does a number of things, most significantly resetting the page number to 1 and starting numbering in arabic numerals rather than romanettes, things which don't seem to apply to your document.

I'm interested to know what "long list of errors" you were getting.  Perhaps that was from before you whittled down your MWE?